# Extract first occurrence of the string after a substring in a Spark data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe (df) which has a time_stamp column and a message column (data type str) as shown below:

**Example dataframe**

```
            
 message                                                   time_stamp
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:27:18
irrelevant_text start  : string                         2015-01-23 08:27:34
contributor Id :XYZ_ABCD                                2015-01-23 08:27:54
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:28:36
contributor Id :XYZ_ABCD                                2015-01-23 08:28:55
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:29:36
contributor Id :MNOP_xyz                                2015-01-23 08:29:45
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:29:30
irrelevant_text end : string                            2015-01-23 08:30:47
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:30:59
irrelevant_text start  : string                         2015-01-23 08:31:34
contributor Id :EFG_A                                   2015-01-23 08:31:54
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:32:05
contributor Id :pqr_wx                                  2015-01-23 08:32:15
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:32:26
contributor Id :pqr_wx                                  2015-01-23 08:33:01
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:33:09
irrelevant_text end : string                            2015-01-23 08:40:34
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:40:47
irrelevant_text start  : string                         2015-01-23 09:31:34
contributor Id :lmo_uvw                                 2015-01-23 09:31:54
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 09:32:05
contributor Id :xlr_mot                                 2015-01-23 09:32:15
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 09:32:26
irrelevant_text end : string                            2015-01-23 09:40:34
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 09:40:47
```

I am looking to extract first occurrence of the string just after **contributor Id :** in between **start  : string** and **end : string** along with those contributor Id : that appeared only onetime, and discarding the IDs which are not first occurrence. There may be multiple such instances in one Date.

**Expected Output:**

```
time_stamp                ID
2015-01-23 08:27:54     XYZ_ABCD                                
2015-01-23 08:29:45     MNOP_xyz
2015-01-23 08:31:54     EFG_A                                   
2015-01-23 08:32:15     pqr_wx
2015-01-23 08:31:54     lmo_uvw  
2015-01-23 08:32:15     xlr_mot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a row number to each partition of ID and start/end timestamp, and filter the rows with a row number of 1.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'begin',
    F.last(
        F.when(F.col('message').rlike('start'), F.col('time_stamp')), True
    ).over(Window.orderBy('time_stamp'))
).withColumn(
    'end',
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('message').rlike('end'), F.col('time_stamp')), True
    ).over(Window.orderBy('time_stamp').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.regexp_extract('message', 'contributor Id :(\S+)', 1)
).filter(
    "ID != '' and begin is not null and end is not null"
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('ID', 'begin', 'end').orderBy('time_stamp'))
).filter(
    'rn = 1'
).select(
    'time_stamp', 'ID'
).orderBy('time_stamp')

df2.show()
+-------------------+--------+
|         time_stamp|      ID|
+-------------------+--------+
|2015-01-23 08:27:54|XYZ_ABCD|
|2015-01-23 08:29:45|MNOP_xyz|
|2015-01-23 08:31:54|   EFG_A|
|2015-01-23 08:32:15|  pqr_wx|
|2015-01-23 09:31:54| lmo_uvw|
|2015-01-23 09:32:15| xlr_mot|
+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am getting a blank result dataframe. I think it's because of the ID. can we chat privately? thanks

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225889/discussion-between-dataholic-and-mck